# easiest way to search a javascript object list with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the easiest way to search a javascript object list with jQuery?

For example, I have the following js config block defined:

```
var ProgramExclusiveSections =
{
   "Rows":
   [
      { 'ProgramId': '3', 'RowId': 'trSpecialHeader'},
      { 'ProgramId': '3', 'RowId': 'trSpecialRow1' },
      { 'ProgramId': '3', 'RowId': 'trSpecialRow2' },
      { 'ProgramId': '1', 'RowId': 'trOtherInfo' }
   ]
}
```

The user has selected Program ID = 3 so I want to get only the "rows" that I have configured in this js config object for Program ID = 3.  This will get me the javascript object list:

```
var rows = ProgramExclusiveSections.Rows
```

but then I need to filter this down to only where RowId = 3.  What's the easiest way for me to do this with jquery?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`$.grep()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/)

```
var matches = $.grep(rows, function (elt)
{
    return elt.ProgramId === '3';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[`$.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) would do it (although `$.grep()` is more elegant).

```
var objs= $.map(ProgramExclusiveSections.Rows, function(obj, index) {
    return obj.RowId === "3"? obj : null;
});
```

This will return an array of the objects with `RowId` "3" (notice you have a string and not a number).

Comment: @Matt - why would that be necessary?

Comment: D'oh! You're right, I was thinking of `.map()`, not `$.map()`.